# Can LangChain only look at specific columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, langchain, py-langchain

I am working on a project using LangChain using Python to answer questions about data (more specifically free-text data) in a specific column. My knowledge about LangChain is limited and the documentation online is weirdly worded so it's hard to understand. The data frame I have has about 15 columns, but I only need to use 2-3 of them.

I tried making a copy of the dataframe that only contains the columns but going forward in the project I will need to use other columns. Do I also need to integrate an agent or retriever as well?

Looking forward to hearing your suggestions. Thank you.

I tried making a copy of the dataframe and stripping it so that it only contains the requested columns but that will not be practical in the future.

I am also very inexperienced with LangChain so if there is a better documentation out there, I would appreciate reading it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.